# Inner join query returning empty set

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with  varchar columns having common values. 
I am trying to perform a simple inner join on the tables on those varchar columns but I am getting empty set as a result.
There are null values present in these columns.
Collation for both columns are same.
I googled for it but cant find a solution.
The query is a simple join query and doesn't have any syntax issues.
When I change the inner to left join I get a resultset but all the columns in the right table are empty even for the rows passes the join condition.

I created two dummy tables with a common varchar to run a join query and it works.
So it is not a bug.So what are the possible reasons for getting empty sets any guesses.
The server is mysql version 5.5.37

```
update a set  a.id=x where a.col in(Select col from b where .....);
```

Another issue is that i have a query like above but when I run it It kind of hangs...On running 
    SHOW PROCESSLIST;
the status is sending data...
What does it mean?
Can anyone help me.

Edit 1
The query is like this

```
UPDATE table1 bo INNER JOIN table2 ae 
ON bo.joincol=ae.joincol AND ae.criteriaFieldName='UNSPSC' AND ae.taskId=4     AND ae.batchId = 44
SET  bo.taskid=ae.taskId WHERE bo.procesId = 44 AND (taskid IS NULL OR taskid = 0);
```

Table1 contains 50+ columns
Table2 contains 8 columns
Unfortunately I can't disclose the data.
Interesting fact is if I join them using taskId I get a resultset.

Comment: Can you post the join that is not working, along with some sample data?

Comment: Syntax wise there doesn't seem anything wrong with that update query (although with an INNER JOIN you may as well put the 3 checks for fixed values in the WHERE clause rather than the ON clause). Unfortunately that means the problem is probably with the data. Does joincol have leading spaces on one table? If they are numbers then try casting them to integers when doing the JOIN to see if they match then.

Answer (score 0):

For your second issue, try doing it as a JOIN instead of using IN:-

```
UPDATE a 
INNER JOIN b
ON a.col = b.col
WHERE ........
SET  a.id=x
```

Comment: Here is the heart of the problem. The first issue is what I encountered while addressing the second issue.I tried to use join there but the join is returning empty resultset. So i need to figure out why?

Comment: IN with potentially large amounts of data can be slow, and a join will often be quicker. However for the first issue there is nothing obvious I can think of but given some sample data (possibly post it on SQLfiddle) we might well spot something.